# Convert text from UTF-8 to Windows 1251

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I try to convert text in utf8 to windows1251.

This is source text Ñàíêò-Ïåòåðáóðã
This is targer Санкт-Петербург

I tested a lot of functions: Utf8ToAnsi, UTF8ToString, Utf8Encode and other but didn't get true result.

Need help.

Comment: show us your Delphi code

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 7):

Let's try to guess what you are asking. Look at the first five characters:

```
Ñàíêò
```

If we assume that they are in fact from [8 bit Windows code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) then in hex they are encoded like this:

```
D1 E0 ED EA F2
```

Now, those five bytes when interpreted as [8 bit Windows code page 1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) are:

```
Санкт
```

So it seems that there is no UTF-8 involved here. You are simply misinterpreting text as being from code page 1252 when in fact it is from 1251.

---

> I tested a lot of functions: Utf8ToAnsi, UTF8ToString, Utf8Encode and other but didn't get true result.

As a more general point, when you find yourself calling functions at random, usually that means that you don't yet fully understand the problem. It's a useful skill to be able to recognise that feeling, and know that it is time to step back and attempt to gain a deeper understanding.

---

There's not much point in anybody explaining how to convert from UTF-8 to 1251 since that's not what you need to do. I'm not going to try to show you any code to solve your problem because I don't know:

1. Where the data comes from, or
2. What form you need the data to be subsequently transformed into.

Most likely you have read these bytes into an `AnsiString` with code page 1252. But at this point I judge the guesswork to be a step too far. If you add some clarification to your question then we might be able to add more detail.

Comment: David, Remy, thanks for answers.

I analyzed situation. You're right.

I received a 8-bit character string in cp1252.

I tried to insert it to tmemo components and get a Ñàíêò-Ïåòåðáóðã.

I also changed nls1252 to nls1251 through regedit but didn't get true result.

I found convert function, see below Remi's answer but received a strange result.

Comment: @Lexi I'm afraid that you are doing this all wrong. You cannot ask new questions in comments, or even in answers to an existing question. Remy and I spent quite a bit of time with your original question. It has been well answered. You should accept one of the answers and ask a new question with your new found knowledge. Once we know where you get the data it is very easy to tell you how to interpret the raw bytes as cp1251.

Comment: David.

I use demo version RealThinkClient library with Delphi XE8.

I made server and client.
Server send a file through http.
Client receive it and copy to TMemo component.

Comment: You ignored my comment. I cannot help you if you won't listen.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to convert text in utf8 to windows1251.

Since you are using Delphi 2009+, the easiest solution is to use the `UT8String` and `AnsiString(N)` types and let the RTL handle the conversion for you (unless you are compiling for mobile platforms, in which case `UTF8String` and `AnsiString(N)` are not available without installing a [third party compiler patch](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/12/system-bytestrings-support-for-xe5-update-2/)):

```
type
  Win1251String = type AnsiString(1251);
var
  Utf8: UTF8String;
  Win1251: Win1251String;
begin
  // populate UTF-8 as needed...
  Utf8 := ...;

  // converts from UTF-8 to UTF-16 to Windows-1251...
  Win1251 := Win1251String(Utf8);

  // use Win1251 as needed...
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use the RTL's `UnicodeFromLocaleChars()` and `LocaleCharsFromUnicode()` functions:

```
var
  Utf8: UTF8String;
  Utf16: UnicodeString;
  Win1251: RawByteString;
begin
  // populate UTF-8 as needed...
  Utf8 := ...;

  // convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16...
  SetLength(Utf16, UnicodeFromLocaleChars(65001, 0, PAnsiChar(UTf8), Length(Utf8), nil, 0));
  UnicodeFromLocaleChars(65001, 0, PAnsiChar(Utf8), Length(Utf8), PWideChar(Utf16), Length(Utf16));

  // convert from UTF-16 to Windows-1251...
  SetLength(Win1251, LocaleCharsFromUnicode(1251, 0, PWideChar(Utf16), Length(Utf16), nil, 0, nil, nil));
  LocaleCharsFromUnicode(1251, 0, PWideChar(Utf16), Length(Utf16), PAnsiChar(Win1251), Length(Win1251), nil, nil);
  SetCodePage(Win1251, 1251);

  // use Win1251 as needed...
end;
```

Or you can use the Win32 `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` functions directly (or a third-party Unicode library, such as iconv or ICU):

```
var
  Utf8: UTF8String;
  Utf16: UnicodeString; // or WideString in pre-2009 versions
  Win1251: AnsiString;
begin
  // populate UTF-8 as needed...
  Utf8 := ...;

  // convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16...
  SetLength(Utf16, MultiByteToWideChar(65001, 0, PAnsiChar(UTf8), Length(Utf8), nil, 0));
  MultiByteToWideChar(65001, 0, PAnsiChar(Utf8), Length(Utf8), PWideChar(Utf16), Length(Utf16));

  // convert from UTF-16 to Windows-1251...
  SetLength(Win1251, WideCharToMultiByte(1251, 0, PWideChar(Utf16), Length(Utf16), nil, 0, nil, nil));
  WideCharToMultiByte(1251, 0, PWideChar(Utf16), Length(Utf16), PAnsiChar(Win1251), Length(Win1251), nil, nil);

  // use Win1251 as needed...
end;
```

> This is source text Ñàíêò-Ïåòåðáóðã This is targer Санкт-Петербург

`Ñàíêò-Ïåòåðáóðã` is not the UTF-8 encoded form of `Санкт-Петербург`, the correct UTF-8 encoded form would be `Ð¡Ð°Ð½ÐºÑ‚-ÐŸÐµÑ‚ÐµÑ€Ð±ÑƒÑ€Ð³` instead.  So, as other people have pointed out, your data is not actually encoded in UTF-8 to begin with.

> I tested a lot of functions: Utf8ToAnsi, UTF8ToString, Utf8Encode and other but didn't get true result.

`Utf8ToAnsi()` does not allow you to specify the target charset. In Delphi 2009+, it decodes a UTF-8 string to a UTF-16 `UnicodeString`.  In pre-2009 versions, it decodes to an `AnsiString` that is encoded using the OS default Ansi codepage, whatever that happens to be.

`UTF8ToString()` decodes a UTF-8 string to a UTF-16 `UnicodeString`.

`Utf8Encode()` encodes a UTF-16 `WideString`/`UnicodeString` to UTF-8.

Comment: I found a convert function, made sample and get a strange result

Var

A, B: TBytes; str16: string;

Begin

A := BytesOf('Ñàíêò-Ïåòåðáóðã'); // cp1252 

B:=TEncoding.Convert(TEncoding.GetEncoding(1252),TEncoding.GetEncoding(1251),A); //convert 1252 to 1251

str16 := StringOf(B); // make string

end;

Result(str16) = 'Naieo-Iaoa?ao?a'

I use delphi XE8.
Where is error?

Comment: Stop trying to **convert** the data.  That is NOT the correct solution for this problem.  As David already showed, the raw bytes of the data are already in 1251 but you are simply **interpreting** them as if they were 1252.  Fix THAT error, don't fix the data itself, because it is not broken. You still have not shown your actual code that is receiving/using the data, like I asked you for. That code has a logic error in it.